# Jquery returning $ undefined iterative interactions

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to using Jquery so likely this is a simple syntax issue,
I am trying to make a table appear on a hover effect(eventually, still testing click) when you click/hover on an image. - a table with a query showing all attached entries in that table. the problem is "$ is undefined" and the line entry is the start of the jquery code.
I've very new with jquery, so I don't know what I'm missing.

the method is - it grabs these values from within a forum - a div and a button, that are spit out in a php while loop, each  button has a value of the iteration, and the name of the div to throw to is "string"+$it. the post value for the query is in that div as a value.

I've been futzing around as I'm unsure if the error is actually on the first script line.

```
<script scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/lib/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $("#viewpopup").click(function()
                {
                var i = $(this).value();
                var jobid = $("#materialviewer"+i).value();
                $("#materialviewer"+i).load("loadmaterial.php", 
                    {
                    jobid: jobkeyofmaterial
                });
            });
         });
        </script>
```

the expected result is a table is created that shows a list of all entries in a table that relate to the entry where the user clicks the button.

Comment: URL is incorrect. it is `.../ajax/libs/...`

Comment: I love typos not in the code I'm inspecting!
but still, there is an error with the first var assignment. 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function
spidersenses say 'this' is being used wrong -  as the error indicates that no value is there... but then how to I get the value of the button that clicked it?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any html... Is `viewpopup` the `div`? Is the container for the buttons? Is the button itself? For starters, with jQuery it should be `.val()`